# How can I fix the error "The procedure entry point ucrtbase.terminate could not be located"

Tags: windows-7, windows, updates, dll, c++

The full error message is:

> The procedure entry point ucrtbase.terminate could not be located" in
>   the dynamic link library api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll

This errors occurs whenever I launch **Skyrim special edition**.

I've tried to reinstall and repair the C++ redistributable package however it gets stuck at processing windows 7 msu and stays there for hours.

My Windows Updates take hours and only get up to searching for windows updates.

Any standalone Windows Update that might help does not get past "Searching for windows updates" either.

I'm wondering whether or not to just reinstall Windows 7 and start again.

Note: I'm not proficient using computers so please explain in simple terms.

Comment: usually, this means that the dll in question is a different version than the one the application was compiled to recognize. I'd try uninstalling MS VCRT and Skyrim. then reinstall skyrim, and try it again. Skyrim shoudl ship whatever runtime it needs.

Answer (score 0):

It's known that missing out on Windows Update updates can cause this issue.

If you don't manage to fix Windows Update, then you're also missing out on security fixes.

In that case, definitely re-install Windows.